# Create function on google mysql gives "SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled" error

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Trying to create functions on MySQL that runs on Google CloudSQL. These functions worked fine on another server (VPS- Godaddy).

Official documentation says that User Defined Functions are not supported, but I am trying to create a regular stored function and not a UDF.

> **Lookup Error** - MySQL Database Error: You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the
>   less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

Logged in using Toad

Username used TAdmin

**Sample Function:**

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `func_getEQId`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`TAdmin`@`%` FUNCTION `func_getEQId` (`pTopicId` INT(11))
RETURNS BIGINT(20)

READS SQL DATA DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
DECLARE vQId bigint (20);

SELECT QId INTO vQId FROM quests WHERE... 

RETURN vQId;

END$$
```

Don't want to disable binary logging

Comment: I think the issue is not due to binary blogging but due to the use of the "DEFINER" option which requires SUPER privilege. Are you able to define the user directly using the TAdmin user?

Comment: Did you try to enable the flag `log_bin_trust_function_creators`? Usually with that enable you can create Functions and Stored Procedures.

Comment: @gabidavila I have tried your suggestions and it worked. Setting the `log_bin_trust_function_creators` flag on did the trick and I was able to register UDF. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If using Cloud SQL, enable the `log_bin_trust_function_creators` by running:

```
gcloud sql instances patch [INSTANCE_NAME] --database-flags log_bin_trust_function_creators=on
```

More information in the [Cloud SQL Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags).